VS Code apt repo keeps disappearing on Ubuntu
This question is about VS Code, a "software tool primarily used by programmers", and is therefore on topic.
On my Ubuntu laptop, the apt repository for Visual Studio Code keeps disappearing. No matter how I add it again, whether by re-installing the deb package, or explicitly as described here, it disappears after I run apt update, even though the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list is still here. Next time I run apt update, the repo is no longer queried.
Any thought?

Not a solution but you can install vscode on ubuntu from the standard repo sources (that's what I do - no issues at all. I think I usually just use the software center like a noob - easypeasy). I've never heard of a source being removed like this - there might be some errant job or unusual security setting. Not really sure. The AskUbuntu exchange might be a better place to ask - its not really a VSCode problem per se more of an apt question. You could also open a ticket with VSCode (github issue?) if this is interfering with the ability to get updates - they might have answers or look into it.

Your question is about installing software using your OS tools, as such it is not about programming tools.
